# How to build extensions to existing packages idiomatically

Tags: go, namespaces, package, shared-libraries, idioms

Effective Go, and a number of other wikis and sites, exhort the Go programmer to use simple names for packages, and avoid something too general as 'misc' or 'utils'.

Additionally, Go eschews multilevel namespaces--it has one level--the package name.

So, package names are simple, one or two words combined at most, and specific to the topic.

And then there's no way to inject new code into an existing package, so what's in 'os' for example is essentially sealed by the author of whatever version of package 'os' I happen to choose to use (very likely the Go `os` package).

But this is where I'm left scratching my head.

How do I write a good library of my own that extends existing concepts/packages such as `os` or `fmt` or something as generic as "extends map types" into a package or set of packages to share amongst my own projects (or my organization, or maybe publicly in time)?

As one arbitrary example, let's say I commonly need a function such as `GetEnvOrDefault(key, def string) string`

This is useful. It could be written long-hand as set of if statements, but is self-documenting and a little shorter to write once, and allows client code to consume and be a little shorter and more concise in their meaning (less visual parsing for 'GetEnvOrDefault' vs. the spelled out code over and over and over again - in this case:

```
// GetEnvOrDefault returns the specified environment variable's contents, or the specified default value if that env var is not present
func GetEnvOrDefault(key, defvalue string) string {
    value := os.Getenv(key)
    if len(value) == 0 {
        value = defvalue
    }
    return value
}
```

This is just one example. It's short so as to fit here and be easy to discuss.  I am going to go out on a limb and assume you can think of an arbitrary, more complex example where there is no question that you'd want to put it in a library so as to write and debug it once, then have multiple projects use and consume such functionality.

What to name this package?

Not 'utils' nor 'misc' as that's too gosh in Go.
Can't be 'os' as that's effectively sealed.
Can't be 'organization/os' as we can't do multi-level namespaces.
Shouldn't be 'organization_os' as that isn't idiomatic for Go.

So where does that leave us?

'osx' - erm... 
'osex' - fun but...
'osmisc' - seems ugly / bad...
'env' - okay, sure, but that's super generic - how much do I want to bet there are already packages more deserving of this name which would be in conflict in the future...

do you feel me?

This is one example.  But I've got useful extensions to JSON, to uuid, to maps, to 32bit math, to http servers, to http clients, ...

What does a programmer do?

Copy such little misc. utility functions and types around to every project?

Come up with very non-idiomatic names for packages?

What suggestions might you have to offer?

Comment: don't overthink until you know the api you are reasoning about. There is not an universal answer to your question, it depends the API and the decisions taken by its writers. though, your example, if does not fit into the main of my cli program, then it belongs to package located in `org/whatever/os` which contains an `import "os" .` and the additions.

Comment: @mh-cbon And what package name would you use for this extension - in your project?  I've got a grab-bag of small additions for a dozen different stdlib or common packages out there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this.

First, even though it is discoureged, `misc`, `helpers`, `api` packages exist in many projects.

If you are writing extensions to an existing package `something`, you can name the new package `somethingext`.

You can use multi-level naming by relying on your users to alias is properly:

```
import (
   "os"
   osutils "github.com/someproject/os"
)
```

If you are writing a replacement for an existing package `something`, you can name your package `something`, similar to `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`, which is a replacement for stdlib `log` package.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library uses "util" suffix. Examples:

- [net/http/httputil](https://godoc.org/net/http/httputil)
- [io/ioutil](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil)

Comment: Cool - I wasn't aware of that.
I am still confused by the long term story here - how they're thinking hundreds of dev teams all wanting to make utilities to extend http - for example - are intended to do so w/o a parent namespace to distinguish them all?

Comment: Namespaces needn't ever conflict, because you can use an alias on import, to import multiple packages with the same default name.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple cases, I don't mind having `utils` packages in my projects. If the function calls are explicit, like for instance `utils.GetEnvOrDefault`, I find that it is still easy to read and understand.

But lets consider a more complex case. You mention using the company name in the package like `organization_os`. That indeed makes the code harder to read.

The package name can also be self-documenting. `enviroment.GetEnvOrDefault` could be an option. If the name gets too big, you can always alias the import to something more concise.

Comment: Yeah, for any given project the alias function is cool and useful.
I am still confused by the long term story here - how they're thinking hundreds of dev teams all wanting to make utilities to extend http - for example - are intended to do so w/o a parent namespace to distinguish them all?
I can use 'environment' as you suggest - but then my 'environment' package will conflict with all others who want that name...

Comment: Well, if there are two `environment` packages, if they have different import paths, alias can help there. But if its in the same company, why not unite all functions in the same package ?
Its always possible to have multiple packages doing the same thing. But its not like they cant be renamed to be slightly different.

Comment: For my own projects - I completely agree that utils.Max32(a, b) is trivially easy to read and understand - or utils.GetEnvOrDefault(), or etc.  I get the push back about publishing publicly under utils - but for a small to mid sized group, I don't see the advice to avoid such names as compelling.  I still don't see a good "story" for Go as a whole with only 1-level package names - name-collision is going to be rampant...